# How to disable/remove "Don't allow localhost:8082 to prompt you again" feature in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, checkbox, alert, message

[image: The image of the issue]

When the alerts popup, it shows a checkbox and "Don't allow localhost:8082 to prompt you again" message (shown in the above link). How to disable/remove that?

Comment: No, you cant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956331/dont-allow-users-to-stop-javascript-alert